# Find command with regex for multiple file extension

Tags: regex, file, sed, find, xargs

I was wondering if this is possible in find command. I am trying to find all the specific files with the following extensions then it will be SED after. Here's my current command script:

```
find . -regex '.*\.(sh|ini|conf|vhost|xml|php)$' | xargs sed -i -e 's/%%MEFIRST%%/mefirst/g'
```

unfortunately, I'm not that familiar in regex but something like this is what I need.

Comment: did you check with `man find` that your version of find has the `-regex` option? Not all do. Are you saying it doesn't work. Looks OK to me, but I my systems doesn't have `find . -regex`, so I can't say for sure. Good luck.

Comment: Hi shellter, I finally got it!
    
`find . -regex ".*\.\(sh\|ini\|conf\|vhost\|xml\|php\)" -print | xargs sed -i -e 's/%%MEFIRST%%/mefirst/g'`

These script will select all the files with the following extensions: sh, ini, conf, vhost, xml, php and will replace the text %%MEFIRST%% to mefirst inside the files selected.

Comment: you can post your answer below and after ~48 hrs, accept your own answer, for reputation points here on S.O. Welcome and good luck.

Comment: thanks shellter! noted.

Comment: Just a note: with find you can also do: find -name "*.sh" -or -name "*.ini" -or -name "*.conf" .... Of course, your solution is more elegant.

Answer (score 29):

I see in the comments that you found out how to escape it with GNU basic regexes via the nonstandard flag `find -regex RE`, but you can also specify a type of regex that supports it without any escapes, making it a bit more legible:

In [GNU findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) (Linux), use [`-regextype posix-extended`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Regular-Expressions.html):

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.(sh|ini|conf|vhost|xml|php)$' | …
```

In BSD find ([FreeBSD find](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE&format=html) or [Mac OS X find](https://web.archive.org/web/20150908010008/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html)), use `-E`:

```
find . -E -regex '.*\.(sh|ini|conf|vhost|xml|php)$' | …
```

The [POSIX spec for find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) does not support regular expressions at all, but it does support wildcard globbing and `-o` (for "or"), so you could be fully portable with this verbose monster:

```
find . -name '*.sh' -o -name '*.ini' -o -name '*.conf' \
  -o -name '*.vhost' -o -name '*.xml' -o -name '*.php' | …
```

Be sure those globs are quoted, otherwise the shell will expand them prematurely and you'll get syntax errors (since e.g. `find -name a.sh b.sh …` doesn't insert a `-o -name` between the two matched files *and* it won't expand to files in subdirectories).

I'm also guessing you want `-iregex` or `-iname` rather than `-regex` or `-name` so the search is case-insensitive.